# Why does C++ thread class create two threads?

Tags: multithreading, class, visual-c++, c++11

I am running Visual C++ 2013 and I notice that creating a thread with the std::thread class spawns two threads. Is this by design? If so, what is the reason for this?

When I use _beginthreadex() it only spawns one thread as I would expect.

```
unsigned int __stdcall Func(void*)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000000)
    {
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

int wmain()
{
    thread doStuff(Func, nullptr);
    auto id = doStuff.get_id();
    doStuff.join();
}
```

**EDIT 1**

When I put a breakpoint on doStuff.join() I see the following output. The id variable matches the 55760 thread. When I use _beginthreadex() I do not get that extra thread "ntdll.dll thread".

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Here is the call stack with symbols loaded.

```
ThreadTest.exe!wmain() Line 21
ThreadTest.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 623
ThreadTest.exe!wmainCRTStartup() Line 466
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

Comment: How do you know there are two threads? Can you put a print in it, and show us the results?

Comment: Just test your code in VS2013, only two thread visible as excepted, the main thread and doStuff one.

Comment: right click on the stack trace and tell VS to load the symbols from microsoft's servers... bets are the ntdll one is the debugger itself

Comment: I also get this strange behavior in vc2012. You start with the 1 main thread. When you create a single std::thread you end up with 3 threads in the process! Even more strange you create a second std::thread and you now have 5 running threads. Any thread after that (8 tested) only creates a single new thread. What are these 2 extra threads doing is the question? They aren't debugger as you can see they exist if you look at task-manager and run the application by double clicking it.

Comment: I am still none the wiser. I installed VC2013 in a clean VM on Win 7 and still see this weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Main Thread is obvious. It's your main thread. When you create a thread, only one thread will be created. The msvcr* thread is Microsoft C Runtime Library. I don't think you can control it but don't mind it. Your code works as you expect.